# Keep Rich Text Formatting in PDF text box

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, text-formatting, rtf

hopefully a quick question for you. I have a PDF that has printed lines, and I need to use a multiline text box to store all of the information. Using RTF, I found that a spacing of exactly 18 looks perfect and fits the lines exactly. However, upon closing and reopening the document, the formatting in the (empty) box was lost and new users cannot get the text to display properly. Is there a way to make the text box save its specific RTF format even if the box needs to be empty? Or, is there a way to fake the box being empty? I am using Acrobat 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple - I put a blank space in each text box to hold the formatting. Sorry for the dumb question.